# how to use, with active cell.offset 0,-1 and add a word to existing value

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I'm trying to do, with active cell offset 1 cell to left and add a word to the end of that existing text. I get an error 91 "object variable or with block variable not set."

```
Option Explicit

Sub ADD_OPD()

    Dim CELL As Range

    With ActiveCell
        CELL.Offset(0, -1) = CELL.Offset(0, -1).Text & "-" & "OPD"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: you either have to define which cell that `CELL` is supposed to represent or only use `Activecell`. It seems like the latter is what you're looking for, so you'd only have `.Offset(0, -1).Text = .Offset(0, -1).Text & "-OPD"

Comment: So I tried this and it gives me object required:  `.Offset(0, -1).Text = .Offset(0, -1).Text & "-" & "OPD"`

Comment: try `.Value` instead of `.Text`. Also note that this wont work in column A because the offset would be pointing to nowhere

Comment: now works perfect thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an object error because [`Range.text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.text) is a read-only property. Changing to `Range.value` should solve part of the problem.

The other issue is that you're not setting the value of the `CELL` range that you created. However, you can just throw out the `CELL` object because you can just reference the `ActiveCell` using the `with` statement you already have, like so:

```
Sub ADD_OPD()
    With ActiveCell
        .Offset(0, -1).Value = .Offset(0, -1).Value & "-" & "OPD"
    End With
End Sub
```